# python printing out a file with a suffix range of 12

Tags: python, loops, range

So I have been trying to get a filename to end with a repeat of 01-12, then start over. Any help would be appreciated.

```
def rname(f=None):
    os.chdir(dir_path)
    print("Renaming Files.")
    print(os.getcwd())
    for count, f in enumerate(os.listdir()):
        f_name = os.path.splitext(f)[0]
        ext_name = os.path.splitext(f)[1]
        br = (f_name[0:7] + str(("{:02d}".format(count +1) in range [:12])))
        new_name = f'{br}{ext_name}'
        print(new_name)
        os.rename(f, new_name)
```

Comment: What, exactly, do you need help with?  If this code doesn't do what you want, then you need to explain what it actually does and what you wanted instead.

Comment: The provided code is not runnable, so that makes it difficult to understand and respond. As provided the code indicates `dir_path` is global? What is it for? Is it to be used in `os.rename(src, dst, *, src_dir_fd=None, dst_dir_fd=None)`? Show us some code so we can try to provide an answer matching your skill level. Why only the first 7 characters of the file name etc.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you are probably looking for [itertools.cycle](https://docs.python.org/3/library/itertools.html#itertools.cycle) to keep cycling between 1 and 12 indefinitely.

```py
import os
import itertools

def rname(f=None):
    # os.chdir(dir_path)
    print("Renaming Files.")
    print(os.getcwd())
    for index, f in zip(itertools.cycle(range(1,13)), os.listdir()):
        f_name = os.path.splitext(f)[0]
        ext_name = os.path.splitext(f)[1]
        br = f_name[0:7] + "{:02d}".format(index)
        new_name = f'{br}{ext_name}'
        print(new_name)
        # os.rename(f, new_name)

rname()
```

another useful thing to use is the [modulo](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Modulo) operator `%` to keep the number below  12.

```py
    for index, f in enumerate(os.listdir()):
        f_name = os.path.splitext(f)[0]
        ext_name = os.path.splitext(f)[1]
        br = f_name[0:7] + "{:02d}".format((index % 12) + 1)
```

Comment: The bottom answer worked for me perfectly thank you!